# Resolving MariaDB removal issue

Tags: apt, mariadb

My MySQL/MariaDB installation got corrupted, and I'm trying to remove and reinstall via `apt-get`  Unfortunately, I'm having a major issue with apt-get freezing after stopping the mariadb server.

This is the output I'm getting

```
jason@asus:~$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-core-10.0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  mariadb-server-10.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server-core-10.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,486 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-core-10.0.
(Reading database ... 361764 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mariadb-server-core-10.0 (from .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.2+maria-1~precise_i386.deb) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.2+maria-1~precise) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.2+maria-1~precise) ...
 * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld
```

After that last line, apt-get freezes with no progress over 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can stop it (for instance via CTRL-C or rebooting), because stopping the server is not a vital thing.

You can then proceed with `sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server-core-10.0`.

Comment: it does not work. Shows the same erro